# How to handle a Gitlab Issue that was planned, but its resolution will be "known bug"

Tags: github, gitlab, release, project-management, issue-tracking

I control a project in GitLab where the next milestone has an issue that, after much effort, we concluded that we have insufficient resources to deal with now.

Because its reproduction is unlikely to happen and is not logical use of the software, we plan to release it with this as "known bug" in the release notes (hopefully people still read those).

What should I do with the issue?

- Remove it from the milestone?
- Close it for this MS and open a new one?
- open a "DOCUMENT Issue #000 in ReleaseNotes" issue on the current MS
  & Remove the actual one as open?

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would handle such issues like this:

- add a reference to the issue to the `RELEASE-NOTE.md` e.g. `known bug:  failing API call when using ... #11
- remove the milestone from the issue
- add tags `known bug`, `backlog` and maybe `workaround available` to the issue

Hope this helps!